# lessc exec task not executed in Gradle

Tags: linux, gradle, build, less

This is my task:

```
task less(group:'web',dependsOn:checkDirs) << {
    file(skinsDir).listFiles().each { dir ->
        if (dir.isDirectory() && dir.list().contains("pmc.less")) {
            def inFile = dir.toPath().resolve("pmc.less").toString()
            def outFile = "$buildDir/css/skins/${dir.name}/pmc.css"
            def minOutFile = "$buildDir/css/skins/${dir.name}/pmc.min.css"
            exec {
                workingDir dir
                commandLine "lessc",inFile,">",outFile
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run

```
gradle -i less
```

Then the commands are correctly listed in the info level output:

```
:flat_pmc:less
Executing task ':flat_pmc:less' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Starting process 'command 'lessc''. Working directory: /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/contrast Command: lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/contrast/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/contrast/pmc.css
Successfully started process 'command 'lessc''
Starting process 'command 'lessc''. Working directory: /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/eggshell Command: lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/eggshell/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/eggshell/pmc.css
Successfully started process 'command 'lessc''
Starting process 'command 'lessc''. Working directory: /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/sand Command: lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/sand/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/sand/pmc.css
Successfully started process 'command 'lessc''
Starting process 'command 'lessc''. Working directory: /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/nebel Command: lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/nebel/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/nebel/pmc.css
Successfully started process 'command 'lessc''
Starting process 'command 'lessc''. Working directory: /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/aqua Command: lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/aqua/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/aqua/pmc.css
Successfully started process 'command 'lessc''
Starting process 'command 'lessc''. Working directory: /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/venezia Command: lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/venezia/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/venezia/pmc.css
Successfully started process 'command 'lessc''
Starting process 'command 'lessc''. Working directory: /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/inverno Command: lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/inverno/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/inverno/pmc.css
Successfully started process 'command 'lessc''
:flat_pmc:less (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 6,5,main]) completed. Took 1.722 secs.
```

By "correctly listed" I mean that if I copy `lessc /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/src/webapp/m3/skins/venezia/pmc.less > /home/dys/dev/synosteel/flat_pmc/build/css/skins/venezia/pmc.css` to run it directly in the console, the css file is created.

But execution with gradle fails to create the css file.

What happens here ?

Answer (score 0):

`commandLine` is only for passing in a command name and arguments, it doesn't support the shell redirect syntax. Try this instead:

```
exec {
    workingDir dir
    commandLine "lessc",inFile
    standardOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFile)
}
```

[Exec:commandLine](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:commandLine)
[Exec:standardOutput](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:standardOutput)
[FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.lang.String))